# How to add a cover when uploading my video to YouTube using Android Intent?

Tags: android

I just use Android Intent to upload my video to YouTube. However there is no cover for this video. Is there any intent parameter working for the cover image?

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
    type = "video/*"
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, File(filePath).getUriForFile(context))
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "xxxx")
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
       addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION)
    }
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    setPackage(SharePkgUtils.YOUTUBE_PACKAGE_NAME)
}
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share to"))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yArw5.png)

I tried to find any doc from YouTube for Android Developers, but there is nothing I could find.